# Laravel Auth::attempt() fails. I use SQLite btw

Tags: authentication, laravel

What i'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 
public function login() {


    $user_name = time();

    User::create(array(
        'name'  => $user_name,
        'email' => $user_name.'@test.com',
        'password' => Hash::make('123123'),
    ));


    $user = array(
        'email'    => $user_name.'@test.com',
        'password' => '123123',
    );

    $m = User::where('email' , '=', $user_name.'@test.com')->first();


    dd([
        'Auth::attempt($user)',
        Auth::attempt($user),
        'Auth::check()',
        Auth::check(),
        'Hash::check($m->password, \'123123\')',
        Hash::check($m->password, '123123')
    ]);

}
```

Result:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "Auth::attempt($user)"
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
  [2]=>
  string(13) "Auth::check()"
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
  [4]=>
  string(38) "Hash::check($user->password, '123123')"
  [5]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Not sure what information should I add.

app/config/auth.php

```
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model'  => 'User',
'table'  => 'users',
```

app/config/app.php

```
'key'    => 'DMmiPAxSYz4O2jG44S92OcdPZN7ZsGGs',
'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
```

models/User.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
    * Validation rules
    */
    public static $rules = array(
        'name'            => 'required',
        'email'           => 'email|required|unique',
        'password'        => 'min:6',
    );

    /**
     * Validation rules
     */
    public static $messages = array(
        'name.required'             => 'The name field is required',
        'email.email'               => 'The email field must contain properly formatted email.',
        'email.required'            => 'The email field is required',
        'password.required'         => 'The password field is required',
        'password.min:6'            => 'The password must be minimum 6 characters long',
    );

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
    protected $guarded = array('id');


    public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
        if ($value) {
            $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is wrong.

This part of code hash password for first time:

```
User::create(array(
    'name'  => $user_name,
    'email' => $user_name.'@test.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('123123'), // <---- first time
));
```

And this mutator in User model does hashing for second time before put password to database:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
    if ($value) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value); // <---- second time
    }
}
```

So I just changed first block to this:

```
User::create(array(
    'name'  => $user_name,
    'email' => $user_name.'@test.com',
    'password' => '123123', // <---- no hashing here
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's some checks that you can do

- Have you setup `config/auth.php` with driver, model and table?
- Have you filled the `fillable` array of the User's model?
- Have you change the `key` inside `config/app.php` ?

Also try to dd($m) in order to see what you got from that query.

Comment: Thank you for respond. I've updated question. I must say that it works just yesterday, but doesn't work today. And I cannot understand what is going on.

Comment: I fount what was wrong :) Double hashing of password. Added answer to keep this for others. Thank you for help.